# putting an integer into a string

Tags: c++, string, integer

I'm trying to put an integer into a string by separating its digits and putting them by order in a string of size 3

this is my code:

```
char pont[4];
void convertInteger(int number){
int temp100=0;
int temp10=0;
int ascii100=0;
int ascii10=0;
if (number>=100) {
    temp100=number%100;
    ascii100=temp100;
    pont[0]=ascii100+48;
    number-=temp100*100;
    temp10=number%10;
    ascii10=temp10;
    pont[1]=ascii10+48;
    number-=temp10*10;
    pont[2]=number+48;
}
if (number>=10) {
    pont[0]=48;
    temp10=number%10;
    ascii10=temp10;
    pont[1]=ascii10+48;
    number-=temp10*10;
    pont[2]=number+48;
}
else{
    pont[0]=48;
    pont[1]=48;
    pont[2]=number+48;
}
}
```

here's an example of what's suppose to happen:

```
number = 356

temp100 = 356%100 = 3

ascii100 = 3

pont[0]= ascii100 = 3

temp100 = 3*100 = 300

number = 365 - 300 = 56

temp10 = 56%10 = 5

ascii10 = 5

pont[1]= ascii10 = 5

temp10 = 5*10 = 50

number = 56 - 50 = 6

pont[2]=6
```

I might have an error somewhere and not seeing it (don't know why) ...
This is suppose to be C++ by the way.  I might be mixing this up with C language...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you new to programming? There are a number of flaws with your approach, which may not be worth enumerating if this is a beginner exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the mistake that you're overlooking right now:

```
    pont[2]=number+48;
}
if (number>=10) {    /* should be else if */
    pont[0]=48;
```

However, I'd like to suggest a different approach; you don't *care* that the value is above `100`, `10`, etc., as `0` is still a useful value -- if you don't mind zero-padding your answer.

Consider the following numbers:

```
int hundreds = (number % 1000) / 100;
int tens = (number % 100) / 10;
int units = (number % 10);
```

Comment: A mention of `std::stringstream` wouldn't go amis I think

Comment: @MooingDuck: please do so! I do not know C++ in enough detail to give _good_ C++ answers -- though I like to think I can help beginners reformat their code for easier maintenance and reading...

Comment: The gist is `stringstream ss; ss << number; string s = number.str();` It's pretty quick and easy once you've used it.

Answer (score 1):

All built-in types know how to represent themselves to `std::ostream`. They can be formatted for precision, converted to different representations, etc.

This uniform handling allows us to write built-ins to the standard output:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << 356 << std::endl; // outputting an integer
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
356
```

We can stream to more than just `cout`. There is a standard class called `std::ostringstream`, which we can use just like `cout`, but it gives us an object which can be converted to a string, rather than sending everything to standard output:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << 356;

    std::string number = oss.str(); // convert the stream to a string

    std::cout << "Length: " << number.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << number << std::endl; // outputting a string
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Length: 3
356
```